# Why my ants don't move?

Tags: java

The ants should go to one of the four directions according to its pheromone level, but my ants never go anywhere. I have a Test and a Runner class to test these methods, but unless I put a different Position in the wander() method, the ants never show up (because they are at the colony). There is simply no link between an ant's Position and a neighbours of it.

Ant:

```
package antcolony;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import geo.Position;
import antcolony.simulation.Simulation;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ant {

private static int TIME_TO_GO_HOME = 15;
private Simulation sim;
private Position antPos;
private boolean isItHaveFood;
private double excitement;
private int time;


public Ant(Simulation sim, Position antColony) {
    this.antPos = new Position(antColony.getX(), antColony.getY());
    this.sim = sim;
}

public Position getPosition() {
    return antPos;
}

public void setPosition(Position p) {
    antPos = p;
}

public boolean isCarryingFood() {
    return isItHaveFood;
}

public void moveTowardsColony() {

    if(isCarryingFood() == true ) {sim.putPheromoneOn(antPos, excitement);
        excitement *= 0.9;
    }
}

public void simulateStep() {
    if (isCarryingFood() == true && antPos.samePosition(sim.getColonyPosition())) {
        isItHaveFood = false;
        ++sim.foodDelivered;
    } 
    if (isCarryingFood() == false) {
        excitement = 0;
        time=0;
    }
    if (isCarryingFood() == true || time > TIME_TO_GO_HOME) {
        moveTowardsColony();
    }
    if (sim.foodPresent(antPos) != null) {
        isItHaveFood = true;
        time += 1;
    }
    if (sim.foodPresent(antPos) != null && sim.getFoodSource().takeFood()) {
        excitement = 1;
        isItHaveFood = true;
        moveTowardsColony();
        sim.getFoodSource().takeFood();
    }
    wander();
}

public void wander() {
    double d;
    double max = 0.0;
    antPos = sim.getColonyPosition();

    for(int i = 0; i<antPos.neighbours(sim).size(); i++) {
        if(sim.pheromoneOn(antPos.neighbours(sim).get(i)) > max) {
            max = sim.pheromoneOn(antPos.neighbours(sim).get(i));
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j<antPos.neighbours(sim).size(); j++) {
        if(max == sim.pheromoneOn(antPos.neighbours(sim).get(j))) {
            antPos = antPos.neighbours(sim).get(j);
            //antPos = new Position((antPos.neighbours(sim).get(j).getX()), (antPos.neighbours(sim).get(j).getY()));
        }
    }
    time++;
}
}
```

Simulation:

```
package antcolony.simulation;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import antcolony.Ant;
import antcolony.FoodSource;
import geo.Position;
public class Simulation {

public static Random random = new Random(0);
private double[][] pheromone;
public int foodDelivered = 0; 
private List<Ant> ants;
private int size;
private Position colonyPosition;
private FoodSource foodSource;

public Simulation(int size, int antNumber, Position colonyPosition, FoodSource foodSource) {
    ants = new LinkedList<Ant>();
    for(int h = 0; h<antNumber; h++) {
        ants.add(new Ant(this, colonyPosition));
    }
    this.size = size;
    this.colonyPosition = colonyPosition;
    this.foodSource = foodSource;
    pheromone = new double[size][size];
}

public void getPheromone() {
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<size; j++) {
            System.out.println(pheromone[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

public void setPheromone(double d) {
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<size; j++) {
            pheromone[i][j] += d;
        }
    }
}

public void setFoodDelivered() {
    foodDelivered += 1;
}

public FoodSource foodPresent(Position pos) {
    if(foodSource.getPosition().samePosition(pos)) {
        return foodSource;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void simulateStep() {
    for(int h = 0; h < ants.size(); h++) {
        ants.get(h).simulateStep();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<pheromone.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<pheromone[i].length; j++) {
            pheromone[i][j] *= 0.9;
        }
    }
}

public Position getColonyPosition() {
    return colonyPosition;
}

public FoodSource getFoodSource() {
    return foodSource;
}

public void putPheromoneOn(Position pos, double pher2) {
    pheromone[pos.getX()][pos.getY()] += pher2;
}

public double pheromoneOn(Position pos) {
    return pheromone[pos.getX()][pos.getY()];
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public List<Ant> getAnts() {
    return ants;
}

public boolean inside(Position pos) {
    if(pos.getX() < getSize() && pos.getX() >= 0 && pos.getY() < getSize() && pos.getY() >= 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Position

```
package geo;

import antcolony.simulation.Simulation;
import antcolony.Ant;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Position {

public int x, y;

public Position(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int n) {
    x += n;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int n) {
    y += n;
}

public boolean samePosition(Position pos) {
    if(getX() == pos.getX() && getY() == pos.getY()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void towards(Position pos) {
    if(samePosition(pos)) {

    } else if(this.getX() > pos.getX()){
        setX(-1);
    } else if(this.getX() < pos.getX()){
        setX(1);
    } else if(this.getY() > pos.getY()) {
        setY(-1);
    } else if(this.getY() < pos.getY()) {
        setY(1);
    }
}

public Position moveUp() {
    Position p = new Position(getX(), getY());
    p.setY(1);
    return p;
}

public Position moveDown() {
    Position p = new Position(getX(), getY());
    p.setY(-1);
    return p;
}

public Position moveRight() {
    Position p = new Position(getX(), getY());
    p.setX(1);
    return p;
}

public Position moveLeft() {
    Position p = new Position(getX(), getY());
    p.setX(-1);
    return p;
}

public List<Position> neighbours(Simulation sim) {
    List<Position> list = new LinkedList<Position>();

    moveUp();
    if(sim.inside(this)) {
        list.add(this);
    }

    moveDown();
    if(sim.inside(this)) {
        list.add(this);
    }

    moveRight();
    if(sim.inside(this)) {
        list.add(this);
    }

    moveLeft();
    if(sim.inside(this)) {
        list.add(this);
    }
    return list;
}
}
```

FoodSource

```
package antcolony;

import geo.Position;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class FoodSource {

private Position position;
private int amount;

public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public Position getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public FoodSource(int amount, Position position) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.position = position;
}

public boolean takeFood() {
    if(getAmount() > 0) {
        amount -= 1;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Test

```
import antcolony.simulation.Simulation;
import antcolony.Ant;
import antcolony.FoodSource;
import geo.Position;

public class Test {

private static Position origo;
private static Simulation sim;
private static Ant ant;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        testPosition();
        testFoodSource();
        testSimulation();
        testAnt();
        System.out.println("Minden rendben");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

private static void testPosition() {
    Position pos = new Position(3,4);
    Position pos_ = new Position(3,4);
    Position pos2 = new Position(4,4);
    Position pos3 = new Position(3,5);
    Position pos4 = new Position(0,5);
    Position pos4_ = new Position(0,5);
    origo = new Position(0,0);

    assertFalse(pos.samePosition(origo));
    assertTrue(pos.samePosition(pos_));

    assertTrue(pos.moveRight().samePosition(pos2));
    assertTrue(pos.moveUp().samePosition(pos3));
    assertTrue(pos.moveUp().moveDown().samePosition(pos));
    assertTrue(pos.moveRight().moveLeft().samePosition(pos));

    pos_.towards(origo);
    assertTrue(pos_.samePosition(pos.moveLeft()));

    pos4_.towards(origo);
    assertTrue(pos4_.samePosition(pos4.moveDown()));
}

private static void testFoodSource() {
    FoodSource fs = new FoodSource(2, new Position(0,0));

    assertTrue(fs.takeFood());
    assertTrue(fs.takeFood());
    assertFalse(fs.takeFood());
}

private static void testSimulation() {
    sim = new Simulation(3, 1, origo, new FoodSource(1, new Position(1, 1)));

    assertEquals(1, sim.getAnts().size());

    ant = sim.getAnts().get(0);
    assertTrue(ant.getPosition().samePosition(origo));

    sim.simulateStep();

    assertFalse(sim.getAnts().get(0).getPosition().samePosition(origo));
    assertSimilar(0.0, sim.pheromoneOn(origo));

    sim.putPheromoneOn(origo, 1);
    sim.putPheromoneOn(origo, 1);
    assertSimilar(2.0, sim.pheromoneOn(origo));
}

private static void testAnt() {
    /* the ant will reach the food in at most 200 steps */
    int i = 0;
    while (!ant.isCarryingFood() && i++ < 200) {
        sim.simulateStep();
    }
    assertTrue(ant.isCarryingFood());
    assertFalse(ant.getPosition().samePosition(origo));
    int j = 0;
    /* the ant will reach the colony in 2 steps */
    while (ant.isCarryingFood() && j++ < 3) {
        sim.simulateStep();
    }
    assertFalse(ant.isCarryingFood());
}

private static void assertFalse(boolean p) {
    if (p) throw new RuntimeException("Assertion failed");
}

private static void assertTrue(boolean p) {
    if (!p) throw new RuntimeException("Assertion failed");
}

private static void assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual) {
    if (!expected.equals(actual)) { 
        throw new RuntimeException("Assertion failed, expected: " + expected + ", actual: " + actual);
    }
}

private static void assertSimilar(double expected, double actual) {
    if (Math.abs(expected - actual) > 0.0001) { 
        throw new RuntimeException("Assertion failed, expected: " + expected + ", actual: " + actual);
    }
}

}
```

Runner

```
import antcolony.simulation.Simulation;
import antcolony.Ant;
import antcolony.FoodSource;
import geo.Position;

public class Runner {

Simulation simulation;
final int simulationLength;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runner tester = new Runner(100, new Simulation(9, 20, new Position(4,4), new FoodSource(100,
            new Position(6, 8))));
    tester.runSimulation();
}

public Runner(int simulationLength, Simulation simulation) {
    this.simulationLength = simulationLength;
    this.simulation = simulation;
}

public void runSimulation() {
    for (int i = 0; i < simulationLength; i++) {
        dump();
        simulation.simulateStep();
    }
    System.out.println("Collected food: " + simulation.foodDelivered);
}

public void dump() {
    drawLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < simulation.getSize(); i++) {
        System.out.print("|");
        for (int j = 0; j < simulation.getSize(); j++) {
            System.out.print(dumpCell(i, j));
        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }
}

private void drawLine() {
    for (int i = 0; i < simulation.getSize() + 1; i++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

private char dumpCell(int i, int j) {
    Position pos = new Position(i, j);
    if (simulation.getFoodSource().getPosition().samePosition(pos)) {
        return 'K';
    }
    if (simulation.getColonyPosition().samePosition(pos)) {
        return 'O';
    }
    for (Ant ant : simulation.getAnts()) {
        if (ant.getPosition().samePosition(pos)) {
            if (ant.isCarryingFood()) {
                return '+';
            }
        }
    }
    for (Ant ant : simulation.getAnts()) {
        if (ant.getPosition().samePosition(pos)) {
            return 'H';
        }
    }
    if (simulation.pheromoneOn(pos) > 0.1) {
        return '.';
    }
    return ' ';
}

}
```

Comment: you will have to debug it yourself because this is too long to just run through.. see the states of the ants and whether their position is actually updated as you intend.

Comment: the ants position update according to Test.java if I put some random value for their new Position. But an ant should have 4 choice every time it wants to go somewhere. The problem is that in the wander method the neighbours never show up.